# Is there a way to restore Github and Bitbucket 2FA without recovery codes or backup phone number?

Tags: github, bitbucket

My android device broke and I lost access to Github and Bitbucket 2 factor authentication codes.

Unfortunately I didn't save the recovery codes or set up a backup phone number to receive codes by SMS, and I'm not signed in to Github and Bitbucket on any computer.

Is there another way to gain access to my Github and Bitbucket account?

Comment: How can I achieve the same for bitbucket account. I have lost my recovery codes and Authenticator app.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Luckily for me, there is a way to do this if you assigned a SSH key to your account.

What you need to do is to run this command on the computer where you have the SSH key:

```
ssh -T git@github.com verify
```

And send the output to Github support. With that output they are able to disable your 2fa and allowing you to login just with your password.

The output should look like this:

```
Please provide the following verification token to GitHub Support.
002de4e72d08f47b0b828bab0224dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf6174ce54ab0040aa7075626c69635f6b6579ce008cacf9
```

If you are reading this it's probably too late for that advice but don't be stupid like I was. Save the recovery codes or set up a phone number!

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. But , I haven't use SSH Key before. I have used GitHub APP on my mac ,I can Support specific password from keychain,Is there any way to recover my Account?

Comment: Not sure. I think only SSH key can help but you better ask Github support.

Comment: I'm not sure if Github has changed their policy, but unfortunately today I was informed this no longer appears to be the case - and that I should fork all my repositories and they would unlink my email address meaning I could create a new account. Not the best outcome, especially if you have private repositories (which I do not, fortunately.) although I can understand it from a security point of view.

Comment: Have you tried pointing them to this question? It was never part of their official documentation, I just talked to their customer support. If they indeed changed their policy I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I just used this method to re-enable my account. I used the contact form initially and was told to send a message directly from the email address on my account. I am so glad this worked! I did NOT want to have to create a new account.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but at my Winbox, I've to run that command using Git Shell, not the default one. It toke me a while to figure out. =)

Comment: Please help! My output: `Please provide the following verification token to GitHub Support.
Error generating token.`

Comment: How can I achieve the same for bitbucket account. I have lost my recovery codes and Authenticator app.

Comment: This worked for me in October 2019 as well. Leaving this comment here for future reference.

Comment: @Vishwanath - Did you reach out to support ? How long did it take for them to come back ?

Comment: Yes. I did reach out to support. They took at least 2 days to give me the first reply. After that it was to and fro for some time.

Answer (score 3):

This works only if you have access to your bitbucket and github via SSH.
Even for @achiash 's answer.

For github as @achiash mentioned you can use

`ssh -T git@github.com verify`

This will print the verification code on your screen.

For bitbucket you can use

`ssh git@bitbucket.org recovery_codes`

This will ask you for password. Enter the password and it will print your recover codes.